# C beginner: How to copy the arguments from *argv[] to an array of strings using a while loop?

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, copy, argv

I'm learning C and I am an absolute beginner. I'm trying to do an exercice but after several trials I can't solve it. 
I have to **copy the arguments in `*argv[]` to an array of strings `*states[]` using a `while` loop** so each

```
printf("You've mentioned the state %s.\n", states[i]);
```

prints out the name of a state I should have input as an argument. I think **the only header I must use is `stdio.h`**.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT. So far I've only tried  things like this

```
char *states[];
i = 1;
states[i] = argv[i];
if(argc > 1) {
    while(i < argc){
        printf("You've mentioned the state %s.\n", states[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

But, of course, I get an error because of the `states[i] = argv[i];` statement.

Comment: `argv` is already an array of strings, why do you want to duplicate it?

Comment: I suppose the exercise's goal is to better understand how to work with arrays.

Comment: You should show what you already tried. Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
char* states[argc];
int i = 0;
while (i < argc) {
     strcpy(states[i], argv[i]);
}
```

You have to include

Comment: You need to allocate each states[i] before to avoid segmentation fault. Another option is to use char states[argc][MAX], where MAX is the maximum expected for an argument.

Comment: Or instead to avoid SF you can do states[i] = argv[i];
But this will not create an actual copy.

Comment: This works, following @aeliton's advice, but I think I shouldn't be using `strcpy`.

Comment: @ToritoVerdejo another way is to set a maximum arg length and do a nested loop. As you would do on a Matrix.

In the inner loop you will have states[i][j] = argv[i][j]